# Laravel simple modal in table not working

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, bootstrap-modal

These are all the scripts in my head function:

```
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

This is my blade:

```
<td>  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
         </td>
       </tr>

       <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Image</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
             <a class="thumbnail">
              <img  src="{{asset( $ticket->imagePath)}}"  width="300" height="200" onclick="showImage(this,<?php echo $ticket->title ?>)">
            </a>

          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

However this doesnt work

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED

Please I have been trying this for days,I need help

Comment: Is head section is in main layout file or main template? and is your blade above is separate file?

Comment: no its in my blade and its not an extension or section

Comment: @webDev take a look now the question is simpler,this opens as  a pop up however the image inside is not shown

Comment: in my console,the pop up opens but inside theres no image,@webDev

Comment: put static image file(from your public directory) in `<img  src="{{asset( $ticket->imagePath)}}"  width="300" height="200" onclick="showImage(this,<?php echo $ticket->title ?>)">` I think the problem is with our path

Comment: and why you use onclick event on img tag,

Comment: nope still the same,however if I remove the modal and pass the img inside the td row it shows the img perfectly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Boostrap modal integration in laravel table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50727704/boostrap-modal-integration-in-laravel-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Possible solution is:** 
Use class instead of ID to refer to the modal because you are looping through the data and creating multiple modal. Or simply create unique button as well as unique modal by putting unique ID in stead of `myModal`

For example:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<?php your record ID ?>">Open Modal</button>

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="myModal<?php your record ID ?>" role="dialog">
```

Comment: it just opened all modals possible with images inside

Comment: did you try with `data-target="#myModal<?php your record ID ?>`

Comment: one last question do you know how to make the button a link,not a this big of a button

Comment: just put <a></a> instead of button and everything else same. `<a type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<?php your record ID ?>">Open Modal</a>`

Comment: I tried that but the style is that of a button.but its okay

Comment: Sorry I forgot to remove the classes please use this `<a type="button" class="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<?php your record ID ?>">Open Modal</a>` YOu should remove all the btn classes